# Java jar no errors in compiler but package does not exist when building

Tags: java, jar

It's been a while since I've used java and somehow I can't import a jar correctly. I went to Project Structure>Modules>Main>Dependencies>JARs or Directories to add my jar file into the project. But somehow when im in the editor all the code is white (no red underlines), but when I try to run it, it says that the package can't be found. What could be the reasoning here? I'll provide some pictures to help. The classes do indeed exist and I can call methods from them within my code.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3g3Vc.png)

[Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yo2kv.png)

[Image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLzxh.png)

Comment: Maybe you have to change from *Compile* to *Runtime* (in the settings from Image1)?

Comment: @Ben I have tried that. Didn't work. But I didn't try to add it twice, one for Runtime and  one for Compile. I'll try that tomorrow tho.